# How do I correctly initialize sigset_t?

Tags: c, linux, unix, signals, posix

It is commonly known that if one needs to reset a `sigset_t` variable it is enough to use:

```
sigemptyset(&my_ss);
```

I'm wondering if there is a standard approach of how to **initialize** such variable to get it empty (i.e. as if user just has reset it with above shown method). Maybe some sort of a macro like ones from pthread API. E.g.

```
static sigset_t trackedSignals = SIGSET_INITIALIZER;
```

On Linux systems it is obviously enough to use `{0}` as such initializer, but will it work everywhere? Because as I see POSIX is pretty scant with defining this type:

> **sigset_t**
>
> [CX] Integer or structure type of an object used to represent sets of signals.

So, strictly speacking, `{0}` doesn't have to initialize this object to semantically "empty".

Comment: If there were a _standard_ way to do this it would appear somewhere in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html and I don't see anything, so I think the answer in ISO C and POSIX is "can't be done, you have to call sigemptyset".  I'm not posting that as an answer because I don't know if there is a nonstandard but supported way to do it on some specific operating systems.  [I can, however, tell you that GNU libc does NOT officially support `sigset_t ss = { 0 };`  Sorry.]

Comment: I think the problem is sigset_t is that it is not exactly specified how it is defined. As it is stated in the spec it is integer or structure type object with no details. Since the exact definition is hidden from the user, we cannot rely on structure nor on the meaning of empty. In other words, the structure might be (theoretically) too complex to shallow copy a constant. Also, maybe for some fields of that hidden structure 0xFF or something else would mean "empty".

Comment: @rhaport: It cannot be "too complex to shallow copy". It's a value type, not a reference; nothing forbids passing it by value. However the actual representation is not guaranteed. It could have bits arbitrarily ordered, inverted, checksumed, encoded with gray codes, etc.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE right. This is what mean. There is no guarantee.

Comment: @rhaport: None of those things preclude having a "`SIGSET_INITIALIZER`" for empty set though; the lack of one is merely an annoying choice of the specification, not something fundamentally needed to avoid constraining the implementation.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE But nothing prevents the structure from containing runtime pointers. Contrived but not precluded by the specs AFAICT.

Comment: @SuibianP: Nothing constrains it from containing pointers, but those pointers can't be used in any meaningful way as pointers because `sigset_t` is a value type. Nothing specifies that you can't copy it and use the copy; in fact doing so is a pretty normal thing to do. Moreover, there is no "destroy" operation, so if it contained pointers to dynamically allocated memory, on top of wrongly sharing that with other objects copied from it, the memory would be permanently leaked.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE: It is possible that `sigemptyset` may point some pointers to static, shared regions within, say, libc. The address may only be known at runtime due to things like ASLR. This would still allow `sigset_t` to be copied (during a single invocation), and without causing memory leak.

Comment: @SuibianP: No, it is not possible for any data to be stored outside the storage of the `sigset_t` object itself because that would not give the right semantics for operating on copies, etc.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE: Can you elaborate? I thought it would be semantically correct as long as there is no per-instance allocations.

Comment: @SuibianP: What would you store in memory that can't be per-instance? The entire state of the `sigset_t` has to be per-instance and have value semantics not reference semantics, so while there's nothing keeping you from having a pointer to some common memory elsewhere inside the struct, none of the state can live there.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE: Yes, but my whole point is that such implementation precludes having a `SIGSET_INITIALIZER` macro, since the address of the common memory may then not be known at compile time. The fact of state being per-instance is irrelevant here.